# Delay closing tabs in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, ide, devexpress, master-pages

I'm using VS 2013 Update 3 Professional, some add-ins such as DevExpress, CodeSmart, etc.  When working in a asp.net web application project and working in code files that have master pages, there are some pretty significant delays when closing tabs as if something is checking or validating the markup when closing.

Anyone know the cause of delays such as this in source view for just closing tabs or some delays in design view?

Thank you

Comment: Try disabling some add ins and then seeing if that improves performance. Try different combinations until you isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue confirmed to be Developer Express CodeRush.  I uninstalled CodeRush can there are no delays in closing or saving HTML source documents now.  I'll reinstall it and see if I can determine what can be turned off and report this to DevExpress as well.